# Finding all the combinations of numbers who reach a given sum

Tags: arrays, recursion

You are given a number n. Write a program using recursion which finds all the possible combinations of numbers whose sum is equal to n. For example               x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+...+etc=n, where x1 >= x2 >= x3 >= x4 >= etc.

```
Example input:
5
Example output:
5=5
5=4+1
5=3+2
5=3+1+1
5=2+2+1
5=2+1+1+1
5=1+1+1+1+1
```

Comment: That's a nice problem. Have you made any attempt at it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of potentially tackling that problem. It's very inefficient though (struggles for values much higher than 10) and also doesn't rely on recursion, so you should treat it as a reference that you can develop a better solution off of.

```
import itertools


def generate_sum_sequences(n):
    smaller_values = list(range(1, n+1))

    def get_all_combinations():
        for i in smaller_values:
            yield from itertools.combinations_with_replacement(reversed(smaller_values), i)

    for c in get_all_combinations():
        if sum(c) == n:
            yield c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 5
    for sum_sequence in generate_sum_sequences(n):
         print('{}={}'.format(n, '+'.join([str(x) for x in sum_sequence])))
```

**Output**

```
5=5
5=4+1
5=3+2
5=3+1+1
5=2+2+1
5=2+1+1+1
5=1+1+1+1+1
```

Comment: [cpp.sh/6iwt](http://cpp.sh/6iwt) Tagc, here is my shot at the task in c++. I can't understand your approach, can you please refactor my code and explain where I was wrong. I don't know why the results are not sorted.

Answer (score 0):

```
def gen_combinations(n, limit=-1):
    if n < 1:
        yield []
        return
    if n == 1:
        yield [1]
        return

    if limit == -1:
        limit = n

    for first in range(min(limit, n), 0, -1):
        for seq in gen_combinations(n - first, first):
            yield [first] + seq


def main():
    n = 40
    for seq in gen_combinations(n):
        print("%d=%s" % (n, "+".join(map(str, seq))))
```

That should work, but there are some performance problems with processing numbers `> 50`.

Comment: [cpp.sh/6iwt](http://cpp.sh/6iwt) A. Yurchenko, here is my shot at the task in c++. I can't understand your approach, can you please refactor my code and explain where I was wrong. I don't know why the results are not sorted.